# merging dataframes by multiindex pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, multi-index

I am trying to merge 2 datasets by multiindex,
here is my code

```
h_d = h_d.merge(t,
                how='left',
                on=[h_d.index.levels[0].name,h_d.index.levels[1].name])
```

about datasets:

- `'t'` is a dataset with 2-level index (`'State'`, `'RegionName'`) and only one column (boolean).
- `'h_d'` is a dataset with absolutely same index and 3 columns (`float64`).

I am sure that the indexes are the same, because

```
t.index.levels[0].name == h_d.index.levels[0].name
```

and

```
t.index.levels[1].name == h_d.index.levels[1].name
```

both `return True`, but after merge I am getting `KeyError: 'State'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like this,

```
                bool,  float1,  float2, float3
'state'
'region name'
```

Then:

```
df = pd.concat([h.reset_index(drop=True),h_d.reset_index(drop=Tru‌​e)], axis=1)
```